# Nativescript - Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript

I'm using the groceries demo app ( from NS). -- Android.

I must say that  if I run :  `tns run android` , **- All OK** :

The problem has  started where when i've installed `nativescript-dev-webpack`  - Where if I run : 
`npm run start-android-bundle` , I get an error :

```
JS: Timeline: Modules: onActivityResumed com.tns.gen.android.app.Application_ActivityLifecycleCallbacks@46bcb04  (346195420.913214ms. - 346195436.816214ms.)
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.nativescript.Groceries/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onActivityResumed failed
System.err:
System.err: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Groceries/files/app/bundle.js, line: 14404, column: 16
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'ZoneAwareError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Groceries/files/app/vendor.js', line: 58488, column: 33
```

[**complete log is here**](http://jsbin.com/rubaneyera/edit?html)

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong ?

Here are the core files  :

**main.ts**

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { setStatusBarColors } from "./utils/status-bar-util";

import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
setStatusBarColors();

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from "@angular/core";
import {NativeScriptModule} from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import {NativeScriptFormsModule} from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {NativeScriptHttpModule} from "nativescript-angular/http";
import {NativeScriptRouterModule} from "nativescript-angular/router";
import {routes, navigatableComponents} from "./app.routing";

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptModule, NativeScriptFormsModule, NativeScriptHttpModule, NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    declarations: [AppComponent, ...navigatableComponents],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "main",
    template: "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>"
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "../../shared/user/user";
import {UserService} from "../../shared/user/user.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {RouterExtensions} from "nativescript-angular";
import {Page} from "ui/page";
import {View} from "ui/core/view"
import {Color} from "color";
import { setHintColor } from "../../utils/hint-util";
import { TextField } from "ui/text-field";
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "./login.html",
    moduleId: module.id,
    styleUrls: ["./login-common.css", "./login.css"],
    providers: [UserService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit
{
```

**list.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {Grocery} from "../../shared/grocery/grocery";
import {GroceryListService} from "../../shared/grocery/grocery-list.service";
import {TextField} from "ui/text-field";
import * as SocialShare from "nativescript-social-share";
@Component({
    selector: "list",
    moduleId: module.id,
    providers: [GroceryListService],
    templateUrl: "./list.html",
    styleUrls: ["./list-common.css", "./list.css"]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit
{...
```

**More files :**

`webpack.config.js`: http://jsbin.com/yoyekutame/edit?html,output

`Package.json` :  http://jsbin.com/roleliqefa/edit?html

`tsconfig.json`  : http://jsbin.com/caxihereje/edit?html

Comment: Check this thread about possible solutions related to this error log https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/67#issuecomment-296144542

Comment: @NickIliev I do have main.ts ( obsiously) - but I don't have `main.aot.ts`. should i create it ? ( it will be empty though. I don't know what content should it have)

Comment: There are two possible cases: 1) Your webpack configuration removed metadata from AppModule. (Tips - find AppModule, it shoud be decorated by `__decorate` or `decorators` or `annotations`) 2) You have two different instances of NgModule (Angular filters metadata through `instance of` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.x/packages/compiler/src/ng_module_resolver.ts#L14) The second case usually happens with libraries that have their own `node_modules/@angular/code` package.

Comment: @yurzui after investigating whole day - (and looking at another project - ) i've noticed  that I didn't have any `main.aot.ts` so I took it from another project  - and not it does work - but I don't understand : I dont have the `app.modile.ngfactory` in file system : https://i.imgur.com/pQ8zitR.jpg - so what's going on ?

Comment: ngc generates `app.modile.ngfactory`

Comment: @yurzui I meant in my comment "and **now** -it does work". Sorry about that and thank you . like always.

Comment: I thought it is still not working because you wrote `and not it does work`

Comment: @yurzui I didn't have that file (`main.aot.ts`) at all - even after `npm run start-android-bundle` . So I copied it from another project ( same project in github) - but then `webstorm` showed me the error that it can't find the file ( like in the link above) - so I asked you how does it work now if it doesn't have the `app.module.ngfactor`...and you've answered. :-)